# Recursion algorithm that creates an integer Matrix using linked lists

Tags: recursion, matrix, dynamic, linked-list

[Matrix Representation (image) using **linked lists**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSDyl.png)

I'm looking for the solution to create this matrix using recursion in c language.
each node is a struct that contains an integer value, a pointer to the next node in the same row, and a pointer to the next node in the same column.

I'm using this code in c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node_elem Node;
typedef struct Node_elem {
    int val;
    Node* next_row;
    Node* next_col;
};
//------------interface-------------
void Alocate(Node** P);//node dynamic allocation
int Value_P(Node* P);//ineger value
void Assign_val(Node* P , int val);
Node* Next_col(Node* P);// the next node in the same column
Node* Next_row(Node* P);// the next node in the same rowe
void Link_next_C(Node* P , Node* Q);// link node Q to P in the same column
void Link_next_R(Node* P , Node* Q);// link node Q to P in the same line
void Create_Mat(Node* Pr , int Row , int Col );//**** The recursive method that creates(Allocates) the matrix structure
//-----------implementation-----------
void Alocate(Node** P){
    *P = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
}
int Value_P(Node* P){
    return P->val ;
}
void Assign_val(Node* P , int val){
    P->val = val;
}
Node* Next_col(Node* P){
    return P->next_col;
}
Node* Next_row(Node* P){
    return P->next_row;
}
void Link_next_C(Node* P , Node* Q){
    P->next_col = Q;
}
void Link_next_R(Node* P , Node* Q){
    P->next_row = Q;
}
void Create_Mat(Node* Pr , int Row , int Col ){
  // I need solution here
}
//--------------------------------

int main() {
  Node* Mat_head;
  Alocate(&Mat_head);
  Create_Mat(Mat_head , 4 , 5 );
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can i create the matrix (allocate and link the nodes as it appears in the image above) using recursion.